# Laravel - calculate in where clauses query (Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm working in laravel 5.2, I'm working on a project where the technicians check the tools of a company, these tools have deadlines, this deadline is calculated by adding the periodicity to the verification date.

**TABLE TOOLS**

id | name | slug | periodicity

**TABLE INSPECTION_TOOLS**

id| tool_id | inspection_date

**I NEED GET ALL TOOLS EXPIRED**
To know the deadline we just need to add the months of the periodicity to the verification date and check if greater than today.

**I'M TRYNG LIKE THIS**

I'm doing the filter query on my model Tool.php like this:

```
    // Get date today
    $today = \Carbon\Carbon::today();

    $query->whereHas('inspection_tool', function ($query) use ($today,$filtri) {

        // Here i need add periodicity months to 'inspection_tools.inspection_date', but i don't know if we can do calculate inside query clauses.

        $query->where(('inspection_tools.inspection_date')->addMonths('tool.periodicity'),'<', $today);

        // I'm tryng like this but it doesn't work.


    });
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database MySql @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Take a look at [`ADDDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible soulution is, instead of adding 'periodicity months' to 'inspection date', you can **substract** 'periodicity months' from **today**. and then compare with 'inspection date'

```
$query->whereHas('inspection_tool', function($query) use ($today, $filtry) {

    // substract 'periodicity months' from 'today'
    $verification_date = $today->subMonths('tool.periodicity');

    $query->where('inspection_tools.inspection_date' , '<', $verification_date);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `\DB::raw()` method to write mysql statements in the fields

```
$query->whereHas('inspection_tool', function ($query) use ($today,$filtri) {

    $query->where(\DB::raw('(inspection_tools.inspection_date + inspection_tool.periodicity)'),'<', $today);

});
```

Comment: thank! work perfectly when i need to calculate the query on where clause even there's another table from relation too